# HTTP GET Request Using VB or VBA

Tags: http, ms-access, xmlhttprequest, vba

I seen a post "Trying to integrate an HTTP GET request in MS-Access".

I used a very similar code, except I entered the authorization key code.

I am unable to determine if the program connected and fail or anything???   I get no responds.

This is my code below, but it doesn't seems to work and no error:
Do you see any wrong with my code below??? I am also using it with VBA Access.
Once I can get in, there is a "Response Body" box what has Json data and I want to put it into a temp file and copy it to an text file.

I was going to use what the other post used to capturing the data.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sUrl As String, sAuth As String

    sUrl = "https://api.ngs.nfl.com/tracking/game/play?gameKey=57444&playId=51"
    sAuth = "NGS AKIAIX2CQ7IEOKPOTKDQ:uNniaOp4jH8jcK9i/EtQhurlilc="

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & sAuth
        .send
        Debug.Print .responseText
        Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is error text. It is in the response which is printed to the immediate window (Ctrl + G). x-amzn-ErrorType: UnauthorizedException

Comment: You actually receive access unauthorised.

Comment: I saw the error and I corrected it.    I had to remove the "Basic " out of the .setRequest header.    It then send data.

Comment: Please remember to post as answer as it may help others.