# How to Transfer a Web Page (Code) to a String Variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

**I'm using Excel 2003 on Windows XP**. All the code referring to HTML I tried to use or tweak just doesn't work because it is probably written for the newer versions.

**What I am doing at this stage**
By clicking a link from Excel I'm sending a YouTube API request, which activates the browser (Google Chrome) where I get the result as text (JSON Data) on a webpage. I copy the content of the webpage and paste it into Excel which imports it in the format one line per cell. I have created a macro to 'extract' all the data, one property per column to a range and the arrays as separated text. The time the macro uses is about 2-3 seconds per file at the maximum of 50 entries which could probably be reduced since only a part of the data is useful to me and the option of copying several such files would also not be needed.

**What I want to do**
I want to bypass activating the browser and copying the JSON Data before pasting it into Excel. I've seen something similar done with JavaScript (Parse) but I don't know how I would use it in my case.
So, I actually have nothing to offer so far (It might have something to do with the Microsoft HTML Object Library, Innerhtml... WebQuery doesn't work.), but if someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it and make the effort of investigating further.

I want to run a macro from Excel which will follow the hyperlink of a YouTube API request and paste the result (JSON Data) into column A of the ActiveSheet bypassing the browser.

Or To simplify: I want to paste the text from file https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt to the ActiveSheet in Excel, or to a word document, or to a variant variable using VBA bypassing the browser. I have no clue where to start looking.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, and the error messages you are receiving, including the API.  There is certainly code that will work in older versions of excel-vba

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846755/http-get-request-using-vb-or-vba

Comment: @Tim Williams: Thx. Poked around for a while, mostly error -2146697208. But I don't even understand what the code does. Could you apply it on my URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sUrl As String

    sUrl = "https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"
    With CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .send
        Debug.Print .responseText
        Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '-2146893018(80090326)':
The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

Comment: But it is OK if I use google or my API requests. How 'bout that. Nice. Thanks.
I would appreciate it if you could point me to some more information about the matter or at least describe in a few words what too google.

Comment: This would be a pretty broad topic to provide links for.  One item I would recommend if you want to work with JSON is to use a library like https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON.  This makes it pretty easy to extract data from a JSON response.  You can likely find a number of examples here on SO>

Comment: Thanks for the useful info, but I was more referring to extract data from webpages using vba, the HTML Object Library or this XML Library, maybe something like a tutorial.

Comment: I don't have any specific references for that, but there are lots to be found via Googling "VBA scrape web page" for example, and also plenty of related questions here on SO (most with useful answers).