# Using Excel VBA To Determine If Text Exists In Webpage

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm looking to a VBA macro in Excel to determine if a single instance of a string "Parts are available for this product" is present on a webpage. I have logic in place do the rest of what I need to do *if* the macro finds that text, but I don't want to waste time or resources scraping a page that isn't relevant to the project at hand. The structure of the page, if it helps, is table, tbody, tr and then td. The text that I'm looking for is encapsulated in the the td tag but that that td might be housed in different tbody tags. That said, the target text is only present once on a page. If the text is present, I need to know the tbody number that the text is in, e.g. ("tbody")(4).

I'm sorry everyone, it's just a tough nut for me to crack and I usually like to add some code but I don't have any code that has been even remotely successful in achieving this.

Comment: For something that specific, I'd just pull the entire page and use `InStr(html, "Parts are available...")`.

Comment: I updated the question to make the request a bit more specific as what you outlined would address just that but I wasn't as specific or clear as I should have been. My apologies on that.

Comment: Well in that case, you'll need to include your code and a link to the page.

Comment: The code I have that works doesn't address this aspect of the issue unfortunately, it addresses the scraping *if* the text exists. All attempts I've made to determine if the text exists don't seem to work. Basically, I have the code that would go in the "then" part of an "if" statement, but no code that appears to work above or outside of that if statement.

Comment: Please include the URL and your code. Just include the code you have.

Comment: Try to adjust [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805024/import-online-webpage-text-json-data-to-excel-word-or-a-vba-variant-using-vba/52806631#52806631). Then with something similar present your case by editing your question with the sample, and don't forget about the website. I am curious too how this is done in VBA.

Comment: Have you tried looping over the tables and checking the innerText for the string of interest?

Comment: Did you try the answers given?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compact function will return the source of almost any specified URL (like HTML):

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function
```

...and then you could use `InStr` to check whether/where your field name exists in the page source, something like:

```
Dim url as String, html as String, sPos as Long
url = "http://yourDomain.com/yourPage.html"
html = getHTTP(url)
stsPos rPos = InStr(html,"string to find")
Debug.Print "Your string begins at character position #" & sPos
```

...and then you find the specific value(s) you're looking for using basic [text functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions) such as `InStr`, `Left`, `Right`, `Mid`, `Len`, converting to niumbers if necessary with `CLng`, `CDbl`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would grab the `tbody` tag elements into a `nodeList` and loop that testing the `outerHTML` of each node (each tbody ) for the search string. Simply exit the loop if string found and print the current position of the loop. As nodeLists (returned by querySelectorAll) are 0 based I add 1 to the number printed.

Here are versions with XMLHTTP (assuming data is present in response) and IE. Note that the position is different in these 2 examples due to the javascript content on the page not having rendered for the XMLHTTP version.

**XMLHTTP:**

```
Public Sub FindTbodyContainingText()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, i As Long, tBodies As Object
    Const SEARCH_TEXT As String = "Listar identificadores"
    Const URL = "https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/Tabela/3653"
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Set tBodies = html.querySelectorAll("tbody")
    For i = 0 To tBodies.Length - 1
        If InStr(tBodies.item(i).outerHTML, SEARCH_TEXT) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**IE:**

```
Public Sub FindBodyContainingText()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, i As Long, tBodies As Object
    Const SEARCH_TEXT As String = "Listar identificadores"
    Const URL = "https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/Tabela/3653"
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set tBodies = .document.querySelectorAll("tbody")
        For i = 0 To tBodies.Length - 1
            If InStr(tBodies.item(i).outerHTML, SEARCH_TEXT) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print i + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References:**

VBE > Tools > References

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. List item